# Char coding in Java

Tags: java, utf-8

I open file with notepad, write there: "ą" save and close.

I try to read this file in two ways

First:

```
        InputStream inputStream = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("file.txt"));
        int result = inputStream.read();
        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println((char) result);
```

> 196
>   Ä

Second:

```
        InputStream inputStream = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("file.txt"));
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        int result = reader.read();
        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println((char) result);
```

> 261
>   ą

**Questions:**
1) In binary mode, this letter is saved as 196? Why not as 261?
2) This letter is saved as 196 in which encoding?

I try to understand why there are differences

Comment: In which encoding did you save your one character file in Notepad?

Comment: Notepad++ show "utf-8 without bom" but I dont see in utf-8 table 'ą' letter with code: 196

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UTF-8 encodes values from range `U+0080` - `U+07FF` as two bytes in form `110xxxxx` `10xxxxxx` (more at [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description)). So there are only `xxxxx xxxxxx` 11 bytes available for value.

`ą` is [indexed as U+0105](https://unicode-table.com/en/0105/) where `0105` is hexadecimal value (as decimal it is `261`). As binary it can be represented as

```
      01       05    (hex)
00000001 00000101    (bin)
     xxx xxxxxxxx <- values for U+0080 - U+07FF range encode only those bits

     001 00000101 <- which means `x` will be replaced by only this part
```

So UTF-8 encoding will add `110xxxxx` `10xxxxxx` mask which means it will combine

```
110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
   00100   000101
```

into (two bytes):

```
11000100 10000101
```

Now, `InputStream` reads data as *raw bytes*. So when you call `inputStream.read();` first time you are getting `11000100` which is `196` in decimal. Calling `inputStream.read();` second time would return `10000101` which is `133` in decimal.

`Reader`s ware introduced in Java 1.1 so we could avoid this kind of mess in our code. Instead we can specify what encoding Reader should use (or let it use default one) to get properly encoded values like in this case `00000001 00000101` (without mask) which is equal to `0105` in hexadecimal form and `261` in decimal form.

---

In short

- use `Reader`s (with properly specified encoding) if you want to read data as text,
- use `Stream`s if you want to read data as raw bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Because you read these two letters in different encodings, you can check your encoding via `InputStreamReader::getEncoding`.

```
String s = "ą";

char iso_8859_1 = new String(s.getBytes(), "iso-8859-1").charAt(0);
char utf_8 = new String(s.getBytes(), "utf-8").charAt(0);   

System.out.println((int) iso_8859_1 + " " + iso_8859_1);
System.out.println((int) utf_8 + " " + utf_8);
```

The output is

```
196 Ä
261 ą
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `decimal` value of `LATIN` letters 
You need to `save` the `file` with `UTF-8` encoding standard.

Make sure when you are reading them with similar standards.

> 0x0105            261        LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH OGONEK         ą
>
> 0x00C4    196        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS    �

Refer this:-https://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html

Comment: The OP already is cognizant of that. So, he doesn't mean that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an `InputStreamReader` with UTF-8 encoding, which matches the encoding used to write the file from Notepad++:

```
// this will use UTF-8 encoding by default
BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("file.txt"));

String str;
if ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
in.close();
```

I don't have an exact/reproducible answer for why you are seeing the output you see, but if you are reading with the wrong encoding, you won't necessarily see what you saved.  For example, if the single character `ą` were encoded with two bytes, but you read as ASCII, then you might get back two characters, which would not match your original file.

Comment: The character `ą` encodes to two bytes (`C4 85`), with `C4` being `196` in decimal. So they are indeed reading the first byte only.

Comment: @TiiJ7 Thanks for the detective work.  I wouldn't have known how to figure this out, but the encoding problem is the first thing which jumped out at me :-)